# D-WAVE QUBO Matrix Form

Tags: programming, matrix-representation, d-wave, annealing

I am trying to write down this [problem](https://youtu.be/teraaPiaG8s?list=PLPvKnT7dgEsujrrP7i_mgbkivBN3J6A8u&t=2322) (friend/enemy graph) in a polynomial matrix form in order to understand quantum annealing better, but it seems like the problem should actually be split into multiple matrices.

**Does anyone have any idea how to replicate this problem in a polynomial matrix?**